# PDO query result includes "PDO Object()"

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm new to PDO, so I suspect the cause of my problem is something I've overlooked somewhere.  What's happening is this: when I run a query on a PDO like

```
$sql = "select * from some table";
$result = $pdo->query($sql);
```

`$result` always looks like this:

```
PDO Object()

{[field1:value], [field2:value]}
```

So what's going on?  Why is the phrase "PDO Object()" always at the start of the result set?  None of the examples I've seen show this, and many Google searches have been fruitless.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What if you check the documentation page about `query()` method first? It's like always a good idea to read documentation, instead of making assumptions.

Comment: why theres no problem to it. thats the name of the object returned. what do you expect anyways?

Comment: What do you mean by *"always **looks like** this"*? How are you *looking* at it?

Comment: @Ghost I would expect a `PDOStatement` object

Comment: Please post the code you use to display your query result. At some point, you are probably doing something like `echo $pdo`, and getting a string representation of it.

Comment: To actually get values out of it, you need to call `$result->fetch()` or `$result->fetchAll()` http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Answer (score 1):

As [Michael Berkowski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/541091/michael-berkowski) explained you need to `fetch`. Also since you're just learning use prepared statements (more secure). Here's how you do it.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE field = :someVar";
$statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute(array(':someVar'=>"expectedFieldValue"));
$result = $statement->fetchAll();
```